# Actionscript 3 keyboard not in focus?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I can't seem to move my Main_C using the keyboard. I do have a menu in the starting of the game. How can I make my keyboards work?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yeah, please show us what you are trying to do with a code example or at least by adding more details to your question. You haven't provided enough info for us to understand the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Flex application, use the FocusManager. Assuming that "myMenuItem" is the object which should have focus:

```
focusManager.setFocus(myMenuObject);
```

If you are in an AS3 project:

```
stage.focus = myMenuObject;
```

Further on, if you want to move through the menu items, you may catch keyboard input to simulate a movement through the menu:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

private function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace(event.keyCode);
    // Handle movement for corresponding arrow code
}
```